# Universal enveloping algebra as the algebra of left-invariant differential operators

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have come across the following statement multiple times:

> Let $G$ be a Lie group.
> The universal enveloping algebra of $G$ can be identified with the algebra of left-invariant differential operators acting on $C^\infty(G)$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89440/universal-enveloping-algebra-as-algebra-of-differential-operators) for example.

However, I cannot find a reference for this statement.
(In the linked post, Helgason's Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces is mentioned, but I could not find anything there.)

Comment: Check Bourbaki "Lie groups and Lie algebras", ch.3.